# In PowerShell, which authentication scheme should I use?

Tags: powershell, authentication, ntlm, powershell-remoting, credssp

When using PowerShell remoting (Using the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet for example), an authentication scheme is required.

The options are Kerberos, CredSSP, NTLM and Negotiate.

What is the difference between them? What should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Kerberos**

Pros:

- Very secure.
- No need to pass implicit credentials.

Cons:

- Requires a SPN record in the executing user’s domain (registered automatically on the computer’s domain only. If it’s two different domain – the SPN needs to be registered manually).
- Does not support second-hop remoting.

**CredSSP**

Somewhat secure – the credentials are being passed to the remote server and may be captured there.

Pros:

- Supports second-hop remoting.

Cons:

- Must pass implicit credentials.
- Needs special configuration on both the server & client side.

**NTLM**

Pros:

- No need to pass implicit credentials.

Cons:

- Not very secure.
- Does not support second-hop remoting.

**Negotiate**

Tries Kerberos. If fails, fallbacks to NTLM. Sometimes secure, sometimes isn’t.

Pros:

- No need to pass implicit credentials.

Cons:

- Does not support second-hop remoting.

Comment: I think when you write "Implicit" you mean "explicit"

Comment: Has anyone successfully implemented PowerShell remoting using authentication methods other than password-based, particularly Kerberos?